# Passing array to another file when button is clicked in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React. I have an array containing ids, `["1","2"]` from selected checkboxes. I am trying to pass this array to another file (Employee.js) when a button is clicked.

I have looked around other questions, related to my issue. The following route,

```
<Route path="/employee/:ids", name:'Employee', exact component:Employee />
```

Here is how I have tried, based on what I have searched.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Button from "react-bootstrap";


const App = () => {
    const getValue = () => {
      const query='input[name="employeeId"]:checked';
      const selectedEls = document.querySelectorAll(query);
      var result = [];
      selectedEls.forEach(ele => {
        result.push(ele.value);
      });
      return result;
    }
    return (
      <>
        <input 
          id="1"
          name='employeeId' 
          value="1" 
          type="checkbox" 
          onClick={getValue}
        />
        <input 
          id="2"
          name='employeeId' 
          value="2"
          type="checkbox" 
          onClick={getValue}
        />
        <Button
        color="primary"
        variant = "outline"
        className={'sm-1'}
        >
        <Link to={{ 
         pathname: "/employee/",
         state: getValue() }}>Get</Link>
      </Button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Button;
```

In Employee.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const Employee = (props) => {
    console.log(props.match.params.ids);
}
```

The problem is when a button is clicked, it redirects me to the home page, not go to the employee page. Can anybody help me how to properly use state in Link to redirect the page with the array when a button is clicked?

Comment: It is kind of hard to help here since the info you delivered is very basic and your code is not working at all. Can you provide the whole React Component?

Comment: @PixAff I am not sure if I correctly post my code here. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

actually I think a better way to pass data is using form and submit method:
here a useful article:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

and another way is define "onClick" attribute for button :

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>

function myFunction() {
//load your target page
}
</script>
```

and for data you want to send it is OK to use localstorage and sessionStorage for temp data storage, I do not know it is your direct answer but I hope this will help.